# Django rest always creating new instance

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, mongoengine

I was wondering if someone can answer me why does this happen.

serializers.py:

```
class UserStatisticsMongdoDocumentSerializer(DynamicDocumentSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserStatisticsMongdoDocument
        depth = 2
        fields = ('id','owner','last_modified','game_complete','level')

    def save_or_update(self,validated_data):
      username = validated_data['owner']
      print ("save_or_update val_data: " + str(validated_data))
      try:
        instance = UserStatisticsMongdoDocument.objects.get(id=username)
        print ("FOUND")
      except UserStatisticsMongdoDocument.DoesNotExist:
        print ("DoesNotExist => creating new")
        self.save(validated_data=validated_data)
      else:
        print ("Exists => updating")
        self.update(instance=instance,validated_data=validated_data)
```

models.py:

```
class UserStatisticsMongdoDocument(DynamicDocument):
  owner = StringField(required=True, unique=True,primary_key=True)
  last_modified = DateTimeField(required=True, default=datetime.datetime.now)
  game_complete = BooleanField(required=True)
  level = IntField(required=True)

  # game_stats = EmbeddedDocumentField(document_type=GameStatistics)
  # level_stats = EmbeddedDocumentField(document_type=LevelStatistics)

  def __str__(self):
    return "UserStatisticsMongdoDocument  { owner:" + self.owne +"}"
```

views.py:

```
class UserStatisticsMongoDocumentList(drfme_generics.GenericAPIView):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsNotAndroidSuperuser,)
    queryset = UserStatisticsMongdoDocument.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserStatisticsMongdoDocumentSerializer

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        print ("UserStatisticsMongoDocumentList -> post")
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        data['owner'] = request.user.username
        serializer = UserStatisticsMongdoDocumentSerializer(data = data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save_or_update(validated_data=serializer.validated_data)
            return Response("ok")
        return Response("not ok")
```

request:

```
POST /api/mongoPostStatistics/ HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Authorization: Basic
-------------------------------------------
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 94ccfc5e-4d53-3118-bd96-87f59d6edeab

{
    "game_complete":"false",
    "level":"1"
}
```

The first time I post this request I get the following output:

```
UserStatisticsMongoDocumentList -> post
save_or_update val_data: OrderedDict([('owner', 'wTHUiRpWy9LBKX2p'), ('last_modified', datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 8, 0, 8, 20, 833558)), ('game_complete', False), ('level', 1)])
DoesNotExist => creating new
```

and I see one instance in my db

However if post it again I get

```
UserStatisticsMongoDocumentList -> post
save_or_update val_data: OrderedDict([('owner', 'wTHUiRpWy9LBKX2p'), ('last_modified', datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 8, 0, 8, 20, 833558)), ('game_complete', False), ('level', 1)])
DoesNotExist => creating new
```

But I should be getting

```
UserStatisticsMongoDocumentList -> post
save_or_update val_data: OrderedDict([('owner', 'wTHUiRpWy9LBKX2p'), ('last_modified', datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 8, 0, 8, 20, 833558)), ('game_complete', False), ('level', 1)])
Found
Exists => updating
```

However I still get only one entry in the DB and if I have changed the values in any of the fields it gets updated in the DB as well.

Here is my DB entry:

```
{
"_id" : "wTHUiRpWy9LBKX2p",
"last_modified" : ISODate("2015-12-08T00:06:24.846Z"),
"game_complete" : false,
"level" : 1,
"validated_data" : {
    "last_modified" : ISODate("2015-12-08T00:06:24.846Z"),
    "owner" : "wTHUiRpWy9LBKX2p",
    "level" : 1,
    "game_complete" : false
}
}
```

My questions are :

1 - Why does it not find it the second time I post the request with the same 'owner'

2 - If it really does not find it (and it does not cause it throws an error which gets caught) then the .save() method is executed which should create a new entry, but it somehow updates the old one - why ?( https://github.com/umutbozkurt/django-rest-framework-mongoengine/blob/master/rest_framework_mongoengine/serializers.py )

3 - Why do I get a field called "validated_data" in my DB entry ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Why does it not find it the second time I post the request with the same 'owner'

In the serializer, it should be either pk=username or owner=username not id=username in `instance = UserStatisticsMongdoDocument.objects.get(id=username)` as owner field is primary key now.

3. Why do I get a field called "validated_data" in my DB entry

Whatever you are passing in save() method it would be extra data that get stored in db. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#passing-additional-attributes-to-save